# Vuex/Laravel pass parameter to dynamic url

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

How would you set up a dynamic axios call in Vuex? For example /api/data/{id} where the id is linked to the user id from the laravel database

Comment: from route param `route.params.id` https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html

Comment: You should provide information on what you have tried what isn't working and what specifically you need help with in your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the router dynamic parameters by doing: `this.$route.params.id`

Example to get a user information via axios:

```
<template></template>
<script>
    export default {
        async created() {
            const userInformation = await axios.get(`user/${this.$route.params.userId}`);
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is assuming you have a route defined with the following:

```
const routes = [
  { path: 'user/:id', name: 'user-view', component: ComponentA }
]
```